# HTML5 validation in Bootstrap Modal, focusable error on submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, bootstrap-4, multipartform-data

I got a simple form: 
                            
                                
                                    Aktualizuj dane użytkownika
                                    
                                        ×

```
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-7">
                                        <h6 class="text-center">Profil użytkownika</h6>
                                        <hr>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="imie" class="col-form-label">Imię</label>
                                            <input
                                                class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                                name="imie"
                                                type="text"
                                                required="required">
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="userid" type="hidden">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="nazwisko" class="col-form-label">Nazwisko</label>
                                            <input
                                                class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                                name="nazwisko"
                                                type="text"
                                                required="required">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="telefon" class="col-form-label">Telefon</label>
                                            <input
                                                class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                                name="telefon"
                                                type="text"
                                                required="required">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Adres e-mail</label>
                                            <input
                                                class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                                name="email"
                                                type="email"
                                                required="required">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password" class="col-form-label">Hasło</label>
                                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="password" type="password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password_confirm-sm" class="col-form-label">Powtórz hasło</label>
                                            <input
                                                class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                                name="password_confirm"
                                                type="password">
                                        </div>
                                        <center><img id="avatar" style="padding: 15px;" src="" width="100%"/>
                                        </center>
                                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span class="input-group-text">Zdjęcie profilowe</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="custom-file">
                                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="avatar" id="avatar">
                                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="avatar">Wybierz plik</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-5">
                                        <h6 class="text-center">Poziom dostępu</h6>
                                        <hr>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-form-label">Wybierz poziom dostępu</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" name="roles">
                                                <option>Poziom dostępu</option>
                                                <option value="ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN">Administrator</option>
                                                <option value="ROLE_FINANCE">Księgowy</option>
                                                <option value="ROLE_WRITER">Redaktor</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
                                <button type="submit" id="saveEditUser" class="btn btn-primary">Zapisz</button>
                            </div>
                        </from>
```

and I got a submit handled in js

var form = $('form[name="editUser"]');

```
form.on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

And validate show without problem, but if i correct all inputs than i got a error like this:

```
An invalid form control with name='imie' is not focusable.
32An invalid form control with name='nazwisko' is not focusable.
32An invalid form control with name='telefon' is not focusable.
32An invalid form control with name='password_confirm' is not focusable.
```

I have tried to delete all required and other but its still same error.

Please notice that form is after show modal, input gets value from ajax get request, after change inputs i can`t submit it becouse of this error.

Comment: any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Please refer to [MCVE] before posting a question. Make sure to add any code related to your error as well. It seems like the program is trying to put focus on certain elements but is not able to do so. What does this code look like?

Comment: this is form launched in modal (bootstrap), all code is upper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. If someone use form inside modal be sure that you self-closed all input elements.